# Why chi square method for feature selection is used only for binary output class?

Tags: chi-squared-test, feature-selection

I am new to statistics. I am getting my hands dirty on text-mining, which requires feature selection as one of the step. I have researched and found that it's only used for output class, which can take only two values. For my purpose, I have output class, which can have more than two values(discrete non-boolean output variable).

I have searched on google. But all the examples shows formulae and computation for binary output variable only.

Why chi square is not used for discrete output variable, having more than two values ?

Apologizing for naive question.

Thanks in advance.